# Retrieve the configuration parameter in adobe livecycle

Tags: process, adobe, livecycle

I have set a configuration parameter containing a path in adobe livecycle process. I want that path to be reflected in a fragment source file property of an xdp. Is there a way to retrieve the value of configuration parameter in adobe live cycle designer? will it be done using javascript in designer ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here is what you are doing:

1. In a LiveCycle process orchestration, you are reading in a configuration parameter.
2. You have a form with a fragment embedded in it and you would like to read in a the configuration parameter.
3. Your form is probably saved on the LiveCycle server.

Since the process orchestrations are called at runtime, you can't call a variable/configuration parameter during design time. If you want to read it in at runtime, I would suggest the following approach:

1. Add a setValue component that injects the runtime parameter into a hidden field ( if you just need to read the value and perform some calculation based on it) or a visible field.
2. Test your rendered from to ensure that the variable value is injected correctly into the template.

Do let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks,
Armaghan.